# Are there spiders in Inside?

Tags: inside

I have quite severe arachnophobia. It is so severe that even though I've recently acquired Limbo on Steam through the temporary free event, I haven't played it yet because I saw a Youtuber play it and the spider in there creeped me out immensely as well,

> especially later on when the boy pulled out the last leg of the spider and used the dead abdomen as a bridge.

I've heard that Inside is a quite good game from the same developer as Limbo, but if there's a spider in there as well, I might as well forget about ever playing it.

Are there spiders in Inside?

Comment: No, but there are dogs...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plenty of other things to creep you out, especially if you don't like repurposing body parts, but no, no spiders.

Comment: The cronenburg at the end has at least as many legs as a spider.  I think it counts.

Comment: Unnecessary spoilers. I don't see any connection between the ending and something that would set off an arachnophobe